# How Deeplinks in Ionic 4 works?

Tags: ionic-framework, deep-linking, ionic4

I'm trying to using deep links in ionic 4 but unable to find success.

In app.component.ts:
**@ViewChild(IonNav) nav: IonNav;**

```
        this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
            '/auth/password/reset/:authToken': 'ForgotPasswordPage'
        })
            .subscribe((match) => {
            }, (nomatch) => {
            });
```

In forgot-password.page.ts

```
this.authToken=this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('authToken')
```

But when i click the link it opens the app but not the ForgotPassword Page and giving this error : **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Comment: I have exactly the same scenario. You can add your voice to https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-deeplinks-demo/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked around the push issue by wrapping the deeplink router call in app.component.ts code inside: 
    
    `ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => { .. deeplink code here .. })
    }`

however I then have a problem when the deeplink arrives in that there is no component factory to handle the page object and an error is thrown in the deeplink module.